# If a value appears in the row, all subsequent rows should take this value (with dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm just starting to learn R and I'm already facing the first bigger problem.

Let's take the following panel dataset as an example:

```
N=5
T=3
time<-rep(1:T, times=N)
id<- rep(1:N,each=T)
dummy<- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(id, time,dummy))

   id time dummy
1   1    1     0
2   1    2     0
3   1    3     1
4   2    1     1
5   2    2     0
6   2    3     0
7   3    1     0
8   3    2     1
9   3    3     0
10  4    1     0
11  4    2     0
12  4    3     1
13  5    1     0
14  5    2     1
15  5    3     0
```

I now want the dummy variable for all rows of a cross section to take the value 1 after the 1 for this cross section appears for the first time. So, what I want is:

```
   id time dummy
1   1    1     0
2   1    2     0
3   1    3     1
4   2    1     1
5   2    2     1
6   2    3     1
7   3    1     0
8   3    2     1
9   3    3     1
10  4    1     0
11  4    2     0
12  4    3     1
13  5    1     0
14  5    2     1
15  5    3     1
```

So I guess I need something like:

```
df_new<-df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   ???
```

I already tried to set all zeros to NA and use the na.locf function, but it didn't really work.

Anybody got an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cummax`

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(dummy = cummax(dummy))
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   id [5]
#      id  time dummy
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     0
# 2     1     2     0
# 3     1     3     1
# 4     2     1     1
# 5     2     2     1
# 6     2     3     1
# 7     3     1     0
# 8     3     2     1
# 9     3     3     1
#10     4     1     0
#11     4     2     0
#12     4     3     1
#13     5     1     0
#14     5     2     1
#15     5     3     1
```

Without additional packages you could do

```
transform(df, dummy = ave(dummy, id, FUN = cummax))
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly! Life can be so easy :)